# Using a sidecar to download artefacts in pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am rebuilding a system like gitlab where users can configure pipelines with individual jobs running on AWS ECS (Fargate).

One important functionality is donwloading and uploading of artefacts (files) generated by these jobs.

I want to solve this by running a sidecar with the logic responsible for the artefacts next to the actual code running the logic of the job.

one important requirement: it needs to be assumed that the "main" container runs custom code which i cannot control.

It seems however there is no clean solution in kubernetes for starting a pod with this order of containers:

1. start a sidecar, trigger download of artefacts
2. upon completion of artefacts download, start the logic in the main container alongside sidecar and run it to finish
3. upon finish of main container start upload of new artefacts and end sidecar.

Any suggestion is welcome

Edit:

I found the attribute of container dependencies on AWS ECS and will try it out now: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html#example_task_definition-containerdependency

Comment: Did you perhaps intend to tag this with `amazon-eks`? Your question is about Kubernetes, not `amazon-ecs`.

Comment: i am planning to run it on ecs, will edit the question

Comment: ECS doesn't have "pods", that's a Kubernetes term. That would be an ECS Task.